# select input in first td when second td contains word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with attributes where every tr id has an attribute_id.
each tr contains 6 td's whereas the first td includes an input select box.

I am trying to automate the process of selecting input select boxes when the third td contains a specific word. I tried do this with jQuery but I cant get it work. I could not get the two for eaches work since I have attributes containing all different id's.

My current code looks as follows:

```
var id = 1;
while(id != 10000){
    jQuery('#attribute_ " + id + " > tbody > tr').each(function(index, value) {
        jQuery('#+"+id+" > tbody > tr').each(function(index, value) {
            $('td:contains("metal")', td[1].select());
        });
    });
}
```

my html code:

```
<tr class="combination loaded" id="attribute_7892" data="7892" data-index="7892" style="display: 
table-row;">
  <td width="1%">
                   //select this when contains metal
      <input class="js-combination" type="checkbox" data-id="7892" data-index="7892"> 
  </td>

  <td class="img"><img src="http://image" class="img-responsive"></td>

                   //contains metal:
  <td>Chain - plastic, left - right, skin - metal silver - V6, color - dark/gray</td>
  
  <td class="attribute-price">5.00</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You haven't escaped the quotes properly in your `contains` bit...

Comment: nor in this bit `jQuery('#attribute_ + id > tbody > tr')` -> `jQuery('#attribute_" + id + " > tbody > tr')`

Comment: corrected still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic process would be like this:

1. Loop through each `tr`
2. Check if the `tr` has an `id` matching 'attribute_*[number]*'
3. Check if the 3rd `td` of that `tr` contains the word 'metal'
4. Set `checked` to `true` if so, otherwise set to `false`.

Here is an example:

```js
var search = 'metal';
var rows = $('tr.combination.loaded');

rows.each(function(index, value) {
  if (/(attribute\_)(\d+)/g.test(value.id)) {
    $(this).children(0).children(0).attr('checked', ($(this).children(2).text().indexOf(search) !== -1));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="combination loaded" id="attribute_7892" data="7892" data-index="7892" style="display: 
table-row;">
    <td width="1%">
      //select this when contains metal
      <input class="js-combination" type="checkbox" data-id="7892" data-index="7892">
    </td>

    <td class="img"><img src="http://image" class="img-responsive"></td>

    //contains metal:
    <td>Chain - plastic, left - right, skin - metal silver - V6, color - dark/gray</td>

    <td class="attribute-price">5.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir you are a master. thank you for your answer it worked perfectly! Let me buy you a coffee, give me your wallet paypal or something

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad it worked for you. If you like, you can buy me a coffee here: [buymeacoff.ee/sbgib](https://buymeacoff.ee/sbgib) :)